# Realtime вывод значения переменной в UIText

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-faq

У меня в скрипте показывает количество очков за собранные монетки , помогите вывести их в поле инспектора Text

[image: https://ibb.co/hKWFTLC]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public int HP = 100;
    public int Score;


    public bool a = true;
    //
    public int Coins; // Собранные монетки

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Comment: Приравнять `Text` количеству очков?

Comment: А вопрос на самом деле-то хорош и по-факту будет полезен всем Юнити-разработчикам. Потому и добавил метку фак-а и дал на столько расширенный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переприсваивать впустую переменную по 30-120 раз каждую секунду вряд ли можно считать хорошим решением. Так что идти по пути обновления текста в апдейте не очень хорошая идея.

Мои варианты решения задачи:

**Вариант 1:**

```
public class PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour {
    private Text ScoreTxt;

    private int _score;
    public int Score {
       get{ return _score;}
       set{
           _score = value;
           if (ScoreTxt!=null){
              ScoreTxt.text = "Счёт:" + Score;
           }
       }
    }

    public void Start(){
        ScoreTxt = //ищем обьект по названию;
    }
}
```

В таком случае текст будет обновляться исключительно при изменении Score. Никаких лишних телодвижений сделано не будет.

важным нюансом такого решения есть то что Score пропадет из инспектора, это нужно иметь ввиду.

---

**Вариант 2:**

```
private Text ScoreTxt;

public int Coins;
private int _coinsOld;

public void Awake()
{
    _coinsOld = Coins;

    ScoreTxt = //ищем обьект по названию;

}

public void Update()
{
    if(Coins != _coinsOld)
    {
        _coinsOld = Coins;
        ScoreTxt.text = Coins;       
    }
}
```

Данное решение менее оптимальное за первое, зато переменная будет доступна из инспектора.

---

**Вариант 3:**

Следить за изменениями используя Observable.

Это решение достаточно схоже с первым решением.

пилим класс:

```
using System;

public class Observable<T>
{
    private T _value;

    public class ChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public T OldValue { get; set; }
        public T NewValue { get; set; }
    }

    public EventHandler<ChangedEventArgs> Changed;

    public T Value
    {
        get { return _value; }

        set
        {
            if (!value.Equals(_value))
            {
                T oldValue = _value;
                _value = value;

                EventHandler<ChangedEventArgs> handler = Changed;
                if (handler != null)
                    handler(this, new ChangedEventArgs
                            {
                        OldValue = oldValue,
                        NewValue = value
                    });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

А дальше используем вместо Инта этот самый обсервейбл-враппер:

`public Observable<int> valueContainer = new Observable<int>();`

изменять значение нужно теперь через Value:

`valueContainer.Value = 2;`

а так же мы можем подписываться на ивент отвечающий за изменение переменной:

`valueContainer.Changed += OnValueChanged;` //в этом ивенте присваиваем текст

---

Лично я бы выставил приоритетность на чем остановить свой выбор здесь в такой последовательности:

3, 1, 2. То есть лучшим вариантом считаю 3. Но, конечно, выходи из своих потребностей.

Comment: Ого, спасибо что так постарался)

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public Text ScoreText;

void Update()
{
    ScoreText.text = Score;
}
```

Потом добавьте текстовый компонент ScoreText через инспектор

Comment: Спасибо, я только начал изучать c#

Answer (score 0):

```
public Text ScoreTxt;

void Update()
{
    ScoreTxt.text = "Счёт:" + Score;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score -1):

```
public Text scoreText;

public void Update()
{
    scoreText.text = Score + "";
}
```

Comment: Не надо никаких + "" всё и без них будет работать отлично.

Comment: недавно проверял, ничего не работало без них